# XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema ... located at '...spring-beans-3.1.xsd'

Tags: java, xml, spring, oracle, maven

I want to run my spring project in oracle server (Oracle OC4j Standalone 10.1.3) but throws me the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/gisidoro/springsource/sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.oc4j_1.5.206.v20090812/buildfiles/oracle.10.1.3.xml:74: Deploy error: Operation failed with error:
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/META-INF/spring/mvc/servlet-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/security/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/mvc/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 125; <Line 10, Column 125>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd'
```

My servlet-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wirefin.snae" />

    <!-- Global configuration -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/config.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<!--     <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> -->

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/css directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:META-INF/spring/jaspersoft/jasper-views.xml"/>
        <beans:property name="order" value="0"/>
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/jaspersoft/jasper-views.xml"/> 

    <!-- Hibernate Configuration -->
    <beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.wirefin.snae.model</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SNT</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.pool_size">100</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>                
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <!-- Ends Hibernate Configuration -->
</beans:beans>
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SNAE</groupId>
    <artifactId>SNAE_1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SNAE</name>
    <url>http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration</url>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- <spring.integration.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.integration.version> -->
        <spring.integration.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>codelds</id>
          <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>         
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.183949</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JASPERSOFT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cybozu.labs</groupId>
            <artifactId>langdetect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-20120112</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My server is an Oracle OC4j Standalone 10.1.3
Java Version: 1.6

Comment: Please edit your post and include the COMPLETE stack trace including all "Caused by" sections.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is a Java version issue, but it works on Java 7.